# How do I use IncludeNullValues for a specific Entity/Class in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

Currently I am using the code below to ignore any field if it is `null`, for all the classes/entities.

```cs
JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = false;
```

Is there any mechanism to configure `JsConfig` for a certain entity/class?

Something like this:

```cs
JsConfig<EntityA>.IncludeNullValues = true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use a `JsConfig` scope block in conjunction with the `JsConfig` `DeSerializeFn` and `SerializeFn` functions to configure the `JsConfig` settings for specific entities.

In your `AppHost` `Configure` method:

## Deserializing:

```cs
JsConfig<TestRequest>.RawDeSerializeFn = (json) => {
    using(JsConfig.With(new Config { IncludeNullValues = true }))
    {
        return JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<TestRequest>(json);
    }
};
```

## Serializing:

If you are using ServiceStack 4.0.31+ then the following code will work correctly:

```cs
JsConfig<TestRequest>.RawSerializeFn = (obj) => {
    using(JsConfig.With(new Config { IncludeNullValues = true }))
    {
        return obj.ToJson();
    }
};
```

However if you are using an older version of ServiceStack, there is an issue were to code get's stuck calling itself recursively, resulting in a `StackOverflowException`. This can be worked around by wrapping it.

So we can create a simple class such as `AllowNull<T>`:

```cs
public class AllowNull<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public AllowNull(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

And instead use:

```cs
JsConfig<AllowNull<TestRequest>>.RawSerializeFn = (obj) => {
    using(JsConfig.With(new Config { IncludeNullValues = true }))
    {
        return JsonSerializer.SerializeToString<TestRequest>(obj.Value);
    }
};
```

The value being serialised needs to be wrapped:

```cs
TestRequest request =
...
return new AllowNull<TestRequest>(request);
```

*Where `TestRequest` is your entity*

I hope that helps.

Comment: I am getting 
    System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Web.dll 
am i missing anything to be added in the AppHost Configure method?

Comment: @Shil Okay I have been able to recreate the overflow. The call to `ToJson()` or even `JsonSerializer.SerializeToString<TestRequest>(obj)` *Which `ToJson()` is a shortcut for*, is calling the `SerializeFn` itself, which I thought it was smart enough to avoid. I'll see if there is a fix for this.

Comment: @Shil I have updated the answer with a work around. It may be possible to have a fix for this issue built into `ServiceStack.Text` but I don't currently have the time to do this myself, though you could ask the ServiceStack team. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Scott, I've made a change in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/e0e44a3313f03bf3b76112ab2040c0ce912cedff) which prevents De/SerializeFn's from recurively calling itself and generating a StackOverflow. I've added sample code to include null values for adhoc types, i.e. it should probably use `JsConfig.RawSerializeFn`. This is now on [MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet) and available from **v4.0.31+**.

Comment: @mythz That's great, thanks Demis; that looks very useful. I'll update the answer :)